# TextInputLayout hint doesn't get refreshed upon recreate() method call

Tags: android, kotlin, material-components, recreate, textinputlayout

I'm using `TextInputLayout`. I set it's hint from `string.xml` to apply localization. So after changing the language from the drop down I use `recreate()` method which refreshes the whole activity components with selected language resources but `TextInputLayout` hint doesn't get a refresh.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update July 2022**

Starting from material version `1.7.0` the bug should be fixed.

---

This is known bug of material library `TextInputLayout` already reported [here](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/2075).

PS: A possible workaround is to manually call `textInputLayout.setHint(R.string.your_string)` again on `onRestoreInstanceState` to update the text. (call it after `super.onRestoreInstanceState(bundle)`)
or call it in `onViewStateRestored`

Comment: I tried this trick but this didn't work for me.

Comment: @FerozKhan I've update the workaround, this works for sure but this depends if you have access to that lifecycle callback where you have the TIL view

Comment: I tried to do it like this in a fragment:

override fun onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState)

        binding.etLastName.setHint(R.string.text_hint_recipient_last_name)
        binding.etCity.setHint(R.string.text_hint_recipient_city)
    } - it didn't work for me

Comment: I don't think `onViewStateRestored` can work. You can try launching a callback from the `onRestoreInstanceState` activity, which the fragment implements with an interface (or event) to signal it to update your TIL

Comment: @MatPag I tried this under onViewStateRestored() and it worked. I am using TextInputLayout + TextInputEditText (instead of EditText)

Comment: Works for me in onViewStateRestored, but I don't use view binding, I stored TIL in a local var in OnCreateView.

Comment: [1.7.0](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/releases/tag/1.7.0) of [Material Components for Android (MDC-Android)](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android) is released.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @MatPag answer,you could add this function in your MainActivity.

```
private fun findCurrentVisibleFragment(): BaseFragment? {
    val navHost = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
    return navHost?.childFragmentManager?.primaryNavigationFragment as? BaseFragment?
}
```

where all your Fragments extend BaseFragment. Then, your onRestoreInstanceState of your activity must be like this this:

```
override fun onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)
    (findCurrentVisibleFragment() as? YourFragment)?.setHints()
}
```

where setHints() is a function in YourFragment like this:

```
fun setHints() {
    binding.editUserNameContainer.setHint(R.string.gen_user_name)
    binding.editPasswordContainer.setHint(R.string.gen_password)
}
```